# Conditional on time difference to show a specific message only when the row didn't started yet

Tags: php

These are the inputs an database rows

```
$current              2012-07-26 15:30:00
1st $row['start']     2012-07-26 14:00:00
2nd $row['start']     2012-07-26 17:00:00
```

When I run the following code with the above current time, I get correctly the "Starts soon" for the 2nd row, but also I get it mistakenly on the 2nd row that it *already* started.

How do I edit this code to return me the "Starts soon" message only to the rows that *will* start in the next two hours?

```
$diff = strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current);
if ($diff < 7200) {
    echo 'Starts soon';
} else if ($diff <= 0) {
    echo 'Started';
} else {
    echo 'Starts';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `$diff` matching your second `if` clause (`< 0`) are already caught by the first `if` clause (`< 7200`) and never reach the second `if` in that `else` clause.

As a solution, restructure your code in the following way:

```
$diff = strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current);
if ($diff <= 0) {
    echo 'Started';
} else if ($diff < 7200) {
    echo 'Starts soon';
} else {
    echo 'Starts';
}
```

**EDIT**

With respect to the question in comments:

If you mean the calendar day, you could use the following code:

```
if ( date( 'zY', $current ) == date( 'zY', $row['start'] ) {
  // same day
} else {
  // different days
}
```

If you mean just that both times are no more than 24 hours apart, use

```
if ( abs($current - $row['start']) < 24 * 60 * 60 ) {
  // same day
} else {
  // different day
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for this. One last thing before accepting the question. How do I check if `$row['start']` and `$current` are in the same day?